# php file_get_contents from different URL if first one not available

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I have the following code to read an XML file which works well when the URL is available:

```
$url = 'http://www1.blahblah.com'."param1"."param2";

$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$obj = SimpleXML_Load_String($xml);
```

How can I change the above code to cycle through a number of different URL's if the first one is unavailable for any reason? I have a list of 4 URL's all containing the same file but I'm unsure how to go about it.

Comment: For a quick & dirty solution you'd need a while loop and an array of the possible urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with for example this

```
//instead of simple variable use an array with links
$urls = [   'http://www1.blahblah.com'."param1"."param2",
            'http://www1.anotherblahblah.com'."param1"."param2",
            'http://www1.andanotherblahblah.com'."param1"."param2",
            'http://www1.andthelastblahblah.com'."param1"."param2"];

//for all your links try to get a content
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $xml = file_get_contents($url);

    //do your things if content was read without failure and break the loop
    if ($xml !== false) {
        $obj = SimpleXML_Load_String($xml);
        break;
    }
}
```